# Which regex gives better performance?

Tags: regex, parsing

I assume there is log file includes millions, billions of row like that:

> REWRITE Message id:"3" | SrcIP:"192.168.1.2" | SrcPORT:"59955" |
>   DstPORT:"443" | DstIP:"192.168.1.3" | HOSTNAME:"m.abd.com"

We can parse Source Ip from here with different regex.
fe: `SrcIP\:\"(.*?)\"`   OR   `SrcIP\:\"(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})\"`

Which one is gives better performance ? Using `.*?` OR using `spesific expression(for IP this example)` ?

Thanks

Comment: I think I have answered something like this before. Using "spelled out" version is preferable. However, here, the difference should be really negligeable since the input is well formatted (right?) and the expected match length is very small. Compare also the number of steps: [v1](https://regex101.com/r/TS4p5c/1) vs. [v2](https://regex101.com/r/TS4p5c/2).

Comment: Measure it and you will know.

Comment: I closed with a post that is very similar: the `.*?` should be replaced with a negated character class, or any other more specific patterns if a pattern follows them. In this case, `.*?` can be replaced with a mere [`[^"]+`](https://regex101.com/r/TS4p5c/3).

Comment: Hi, actually it is not exactly same question. In the capture group when trying to write expression for IPaddress which one gives better performance.
 I'll use [^"] ok, but which one should I choose one of these two `.*?` or `\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}` thanks.